# Which method calls when we tap on to the start recording button in UIImagePickerViewController when capturing a video in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need a help from your side that I am capturing a video through UIImagePickerViewController and I need to know which method calls when we tap on to the start capturing button to set a timer to get the duration of the captured video.

Guy's please help me to get rid of this.

Thanks in advance,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system does not inform you of this event. However, you could replace the standard UI with a custom overlay view containing your own start/stop button. When the user taps that button, start/stop your timer and call `startVideoCapture`/`stopVideoCapture`.

Comment: How can we replace the standard UI with custom Button can u please suggest me with some code?

Comment: See the UIImagePickerController documentation for `cameraOverlayView` and `showsCameraControls`.

Comment: I had done this with picker.showsCameraControls = NO; Its working fine but I need to get the front camera control also is it possible?

Comment: Then add another button and when the user taps it, switch to the other camera. What's so hard about this? All the info is in the documentation for `UIImagePickerController`. And it's not even a particularly long document.

Comment: sorry, Actually I am new so these many questions.Is there any property to set the front camera and to play the captured video.Please can you explain with some code.